# Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object HTMLLIElement]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays

Tags: angular

Getting an error in console

> Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object HTMLLIElement]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.

*component.ts*

```
export class NotificationComponent implements OnInit {
    notifications: Notification[] = [];

    ngOnInit() {
        this.notifications = [
            { 
                field: { 
                    name:"Commodity", 
                    description: "Commodity",
                    oldValue: "test",
                    newValue:"test1", 
                    message: "message"
                },
                isActive: true, 
                CreatedBy: "sri", 
                CreatedDate: new Date(), 
                UpdatedBy: "sri", 
                UpdatedDate: new Date(),
                ClientId: "client id", 
                Id: 2, 
                Guid: "guid" 
            },
            {
                field: { 
                    name:"ArrivalDate",
                    description: "Arrival Date",
                    oldValue: "test2",
                    newValue:"test2",
                    message: "message"
                },
                isActive: true, 
                CreatedBy: "sri", 
                CreatedDate: new Date(), 
                UpdatedBy: "sri", 
                UpdatedDate: new Date(),
                ClientId: "client id", 
                Id: 2, 
                Guid: "guid"
            }
        ];
    }
}
```

In my html template:

```
<ul >
    <li *ngFor="let n of notifications"> 
            <span>{{n.field.name}} </span>  
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Is your ngFor looping on **notifications** or **notifications1**? (asking this based on your comment on the answer below)

Comment: Well..Thats on notifications..Sorry Typo.. .

Answer (score 0):

With the JSON you provided above, it works good! just verify the JSON in the sample and yours are  matching,

**[`STACKBLITZ DEMO`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngfor-simple?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)**

Comment: Thanks for your response
I verified that my prob happens when i use it to populate inside a facebook type notification that i'm implementing.

Comment: <ul >
        <li #notifications [ngClass]="{'active-top-menu':activeTopbarItem === notifications}">
            <a href="#" (click)="onTopbarItemClick($event,notifications)">
                <i class="topbar-icon material-icons">timer</i>
                <span class="topbar-badge animated rubberBand">4</span>
          
            </a>
            <ul class="ultima-menu animated fadeInDown">
                  <li *ngFor="let n of notifications1" role="menuitem"> 
                           <span>{{n.field.name}} </span>  
                 </li>

Comment: what is this ? add to your question

Answer (score 0):

From your comment above, it looks like you've got both a template reference called notifications and a variable of type Notification[] which contains your notifications.

Try changing one of the names to make sure they don't share the same.